# Active Directory SQL rights in java

Tags: java, sql, spring, active-directory

I have been told at my current job that we are not using SQL id's for database access and that I will need to get the SQL rights from active directory.  I have never heard of this being done in java and was just curious if anyone has done this and if so could you please point me in the right direction.  We are using the spring framework 3.2 and right now our data sources are being managed by spring.  As I said before getting access to the database through active directory is something I've never seen.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? (What is a "SQL id"?)

Comment: MSFT AD is just another implementation of an LDAP.  LDAPs have authentication and authorization functions.  See if section 19.5 of this doc applies.  http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ldap.html

Comment: By SQL id I just mean the database has a username and password combo that gives me access to the database.  Instead they want to get the database connection right from active directory meaning your active directory gives you the database connection rather than getting your data source from a jdbc URL using the login password combo.  I have used LDAP for user authentication but never to actually get my data source.

Comment: Oh and its SQL server 2008.

Comment: Basically they want you to authenticate your data source through active directory so if you the user have access to that database then through active directory you can grab that resource and use it.